# Distribute messages equally into partitions in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am new in Kafka, so i have some issues related on basic things for Kafka. I wanted to distribute all messages equally to all over partitions.

As I know, Producer chose the partition based on key hashing (If key is available) using default **Partitioner** hash algorithm (Random, Consistent, Murmur2, sticky etc.). Which is great. But I want to distribute the messages to all partitions.  Like:

Topic: "Test"
Partition: 3

Now, If i produce messages (Key Available) then I want to distribute those messages equally like:

Partition 1: 1,4,7,10
Partition 2: 2,5,8
Partition 3: 3,6,9

So, how can i distribute messages equally to all partition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default partitioner chooses partition based on the hash of key *if* a key is available and no partition is specified in the record itself. Otherwise (i.e. no key is present and no partition is specified) it chooses the partition in a round-robin fashion (Kafka<2.4, read below).

```
public int partition(String key, int partitionNum) {
  byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes();
  return toPositive(murmur2(keyBytes)) % partitionNum;
}
```

For a handful number of keys, using the default partitioner may not give you even data distribution, as `toPositive(murmur2(keyBytes)) % numberOfPartitions` will have collisions. The best way is for the producer to take responsibility and decide which partition to send the message to using CustomPartitioner based on your business use-case.

> Kafka guarantees that any consumer of a given ***topic-partition*** will always read that partition's events in exactly the same order as they were written.

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction

One thing to note here is, that although eliminating data skewness is important - The order of messages going in different partitions in a topic may or may not be in-order - this may have consequences based on your use-case. But within a Partition will they'll be stored in the order, Thus keep related messages in the same partition.

For e.g. In an E-commerce delivery-related environment, Messages related to an OrderID should come in order (you don't want "Out-For-Delivery" to be after "Delivered"), thus messages for specific order_id should go into the same partition.

**Update:**
As mentioned in the comment, Kafka ≥ v2.4 uses Sticky Partitioner as the default partitioner.

> The sticky partitioner addresses the problem of spreading out records without keys into smaller batches by picking a single partition to send all non-keyed records. Once the batch at that partition is filled or otherwise completed, the sticky partitioner randomly chooses and “sticks” to a new partition. That way, over a larger period of time, records are about evenly distributed among all the partitions while getting the added benefit of larger batch sizes.

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-producer-improvements-sticky-partitioner/

This means Kafka producers don’t immediately send records but keeps a batch of records for a specific topic with no keys and no assigned partition and will send to the same partition until the batch is ready to be sent. When a new batch is created, a new partition is chosen.

Effectively, the partitioner assigns records to the same partition until the batch is sent based on `batch.size` and `linger.ms`, once that batch is sent, a new partition will be used. Thus messages may not necessarily be evenly distributed.

Further Reading:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-480%3A+Sticky+Partitioner

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-794%3A+Strictly+Uniform+Sticky+Partitioner#KIP794:StrictlyUniformStickyPartitioner-UniformStickyBatchSize

https://www.confluent.io/blog/5-things-every-kafka-developer-should-know/#tip-2-new-sticky-partitioner

https://aiven.io/blog/balance-data-across-kafka-partitions#challenge-of-uneven-record-distribution

Comment: Thank you from my heart for all the helpful information you gave me. But If I'm not wrong, When there’s no partition and no key specified, the default partitioner sends data in a round-robin fashion in Kafka ≤ v2.3 But from Kafka ≥ v2.4 it uses Sticky Partitioner as a default partitioner.

Comment: Thanks @MahmudulHasanSayan for mentioning the same, I'll update the answer, There are multiple of scenarios when uneven distribution can happen in the case of Sticky as well, the gist is it uses batch so a batch would still go to same partition before next batch is started.

Answer (score 1):

Ronak explained very precisely.
You could achieve distribution of the messages over partitions evenly by implementing Partitioner interface regardless of the key.

- New sticky version

  ```java
      public class SimplePartitioner implements Partitioner {
          private final StickyPartitionCache stickyPartitionCache = new StickyPartitionCache();

          public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
          }

          @Override
          public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
              return partition(topic, key, keyBytes, value, valueBytes, cluster, cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic).size());
          }

          public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster,
                       int numPartitions) {
              return stickyPartitionCache.partition(topic, cluster);
          }

          @Override
          public void close() {
          }
      }
  ```
- Old version - see this link: hhttps://github.com/sharefeel/kafka-simple-partitioner/blob/0.8.2/SimplePartitioner.java

Don't forget this. Target partitions of SimplePartitioner and DefaultPartitioner are not same. But normally same.

- If key is given, DefaultPartitioner will return one number from 0 to numPartition-1.
- But SimplePartition always returns number of stikyPartitionCache.partitionCache.partition()'s value.

If there's an unavailable partition (all replicas of that parition down), producing will fail with DefaulPartitioner. But Simpartition can make producing success.
I tested about this with old version of SimplePartitioner but did not with newer one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question best:

https://rajatjain-ix.medium.com/whats-wrong-with-kafka-b53d0549677a

So, there are two solutions available..

1. You don't specify any partition_key. In this case, the DefaultPartitioner will automatically round-robin the messages across the partitions.
2. You use a (incremental uuid) % (count of partitions) as the partition number in Producer API. This way you are manually telling it to round-robin the messages to partitions.