# Kafka is not sending messages to other partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-topic, kafka-partition

Apache Kafka installed on Mac (Intel).
Single local producer and single local consumer.
1 topic with 3 partitions and 1 replication factor is created:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic animal --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1
```

Producer code:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic animal
```

Producer Messages:

```
>alligator
>crocodile
>tiger
```

When producing messages (manually via producer-console), all go into the same partition. Shouldn't they get distributed across partitions?

I've tried with 3 records (as above), but they get sent to 1 partition only. Checked within tmp/kafka-logs/topic-0/00***00.log
Other logs in topic-* are empty.

I've tried with tens of records, but no luck.

I even increased the default partition configuration (num.partitions=3) within 'config/server.properties', but no luck.

I've also tried with different topics, but no luck.

Comment: Can you add more details about your i.e. payload keys, batch size etc?

Comment: Also, check my answer to this question, might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74780332/distribute-messages-equally-into-partitions-in-kafka/74784296?noredirect=1#comment132131442_74784296

Comment: @RonakJain - I've got no keys, no batches simple text in a local dummy producer via bin/kafka-console-producer.sh

Comment: How exactly do you invoke the `kafka-console-producer`?

Comment: @Prathamesh ok, what is your Kafka version and config?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu - yes, I'm invoking Kafka console producer. I am only trying out the round-robin approach without any keys

Comment: Kafka version 3.3.1, no config changes except num.partitions=3 in server.properties

Comment: @Prathamesh "yes, I'm invoking..." is hardly an answer to "How exactly do you invoke...?"

Comment: @CostiCiudatu I misread that, here's how I'm invoking the console producer: bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic animal

Comment: @CostiCiudatu I've also tried with --broker-list localhost:9092, instead of bootstrap-server

Comment: @Prathamesh Have you checked batch.size? Also did you try sending messages in one go or in multiple invocations?

Comment: @RonakJain the batch.size is left as default under producer.properties. I've updated the prompt with more details on how I invoke the console-producer.

Comment: @Prathamesh The default is 16384 for console producer, so as mentioned in my other answer, it would stick to a single partition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with kafka 2.4, the default partitioner was changed from round-robin to [sticky](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-producer-improvements-sticky-partitioner/), which will stick to the same partition (pun intended) for an entire batch.

With my kafka version, the `kafka-console-producer` uses a default batch size of 16384, so once you produce enough messages to fill that buffer, the partition will change.

Comment: You can override the partitioner with property flag on the CLI

Comment: I am currently watching a course on Kafka . the tutor was using Kafka >2.4 but still had the round robin working just fine. when I did the same thing as him on cl all my messages where going to the same partition(sticky). the tutor was on mac and I am on Linux so I thought maybe it has something to do with the OS one might be on too?like different config? I might be wrong tho.or maybe it was because of the version difference.he was working with  kafka_2.13-3.1.0 and I am working with kafka_2.13-3.6.1. maybe I should just stick to keys to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

If a producer, produces messages with the same key then it’s guaranteed to be produced on the same partition. so in your case if you want it to be consumed by different partitions than make sure to publish it with different keys.
You will need to set below property.

```
--property parse.key=true
```

See below command to produce record with key.

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic first_topic --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=,

> key1,value1
> key2,value2
```